# Eclipse error processing file (commencingResolution failed)

Tags: eclipse, grails

All of a sudden I am getting errors in my eclipse grails project (GGTS 3.6.4).  I'm wondering if this might be due to codehaus being terminated...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 4 2015-06-07 07:47:09.622
!MESSAGE Internal groovy compiler error.
!STACK 0
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/paul/Documents/GrailsWorkspace/Invoicer/target/work/plugins/fields-1.5.1/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/formfields/FormFieldsTagLib.groovy' commencingResolution failed: declaration found, but unexpectedly found no scope for grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib$BeanAndPrefix
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:1027)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:648)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.processToPhase(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:202)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:2202)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:827)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyEclipseBug: commencingResolution failed: declaration found, but unexpectedly found no scope for grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib$BeanAndPrefix
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.JDTResolver.commencingResolution(JDTResolver.java:511)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1283)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:167)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.JDTResolver.startResolving(JDTResolver.java:565)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:714)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:1018)
        ... 7 more
```

I have tried refreshing dependencies as well as removing target and target-eclipse directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eclipse just lost its mind.  I deleted the project then re-imported it.  Eclipse told me that it looked like a Grails project but needed to recreate the project file.  I allowed it to do so and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

got same error (just using Groovy btw) and a project clean did the trick